# Android: Blank space with TitleBar spacing in the top of my screen

Tags: java, android

I have run in to an irritating bug that moves all my layouts by the spacing of the titlebar, without the titlebar being there. It has this space when running in an emulator "Profile: Nexus 5x", but looks normal on my Oneplus 3.

I have tried removing it by treating it as a titlebar, but i'm suspecting it might be somethings else.

Like som kind of universal padding throught all my layouts. I'm so stumped on this.

It can also be seen in the "Design" window when editing xml.

EDIT EDIT EDIT ========================================= EDIT EDIT EDIT

I found out that using the roughhike bottomBar library and trying to display more than 3 icons, propmpted the extra space on the top of the screen for some reason. After using the native design library "BottomNavigationView" i have had no problem.

EDIT EDIT EDIT ========================================= EDIT EDIT EDIT

Any idea what could be spacing as a tiltebar, but not be the titlebar?

[image]

**Android manifest.xml**:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

**Style.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>


        </style>

        <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        </style>
```

**Activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**content_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.razze.roomee.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.razze.roomee;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static Context mContext;
    private static Point windowsSize;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    BottomBar bottomBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // HomeActivity uses these
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        windowsSize = Utility.getDisplaySize(getWindowManager());

        // Declares bottomBar and it's items
        bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomBar);
        bottomBar = BottomBar.attach(this, savedInstanceState);
        bottomBar.setItems(R.menu.bottombar_menu);
        bottomBar.setDefaultTabPosition(2);

        // BottomBar OnClickListener
        bottomBar.setOnMenuTabClickListener(new OnMenuTabClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onMenuTabSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {

                fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                System.out.println("Menu selected: " + menuItemId);

                switch (menuItemId){

                    case R.id.preferences:

                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                 .replace(R.id.content_main,
                                            new PreferencesActivity())
                                 .commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.matches:

                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.content_main,
                                            new MatchesActivity())
                                    .commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.settings:

                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                 .replace(R.id.content_main,
                                            new SettingsActivity())
                                 .commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.home:

                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.content_main,
                                            new HomeActivity())
                                    .commit();
                        break;

                    case R.id.message:

                           fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                   .replace(R.id.content_main,
                                           new MessageActivity())
                                   .commit();
                        break;
                }

            }

            // When an icon in BottomBar that is selected, gets selected.
            @Override
            public void onMenuTabReSelected(@IdRes int menuItemId) {     }

        });

      // Colors the bottombar (DOESNT WORK FOR SOME REASON
      //bottomBar.mapColorForTab(0, "#FF9800");
      //bottomBar.mapColorForTab(1, "#FF5252");
      //bottomBar.mapColorForTab(2, "#7B1FA2");
      //bottomBar.mapColorForTab(3, "#FFF352");
      //bottomBar.mapColorForTab(4, "#455FA2");


    }

    // HomeActivity uses these
    public static Context getMainContext(){ return mContext; }

    public static Point getWindowSize(){ return windowsSize; }



}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, would be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to make the `activity` fullscreen u can use:

**Method 1**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
</activity>
```

in res/values/styles.xml;

```
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**Method 2:** use `requestWindowFeature` function

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);        

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Also remove unnecessary padding from top or bottom

Comment: Method 1: Tried, but it ran in to a binary xml error: " android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>"

Method 2: Didn't work, just removed the status bar

Comment: check the edit..and make sure u don't have other view like `appbar`, `toolbar` in your layout..from the code u posted there is not much to find..

Comment: Didn't work either. Can't see any difference. Removing the android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in my app_bar_main didn't do the trick either.

Comment: I will gladly provide the code if you could tell me what you wanna see.

Comment: ..That is my entire activity_main. It's still early in the process. And, nothing in the my layouts for my fragments suggest anything that looks like padding or should create that spacing. 

Thanks for your time by the way, i really appreciate you looking at it.

Comment: did u run the code in device...cause android studio shows default action bar at design view even though it is removed at runtime

Comment: Something i forgot to mention actually, it only has that top space when running in the emulator "Profile: Nexus 5x". But running on my OnePlus 3, it looks normal.

Comment: test the code on real device: cause emulator os may contain bugs..(maybe) also remove this line `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` as you are not using `appbar/toolbar` layout for scrolling

Comment: Thanks, i have suspected that aswell, but i Imagine i should keep Looking because it should work everywhere. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Modify **content_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/content_main"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
 tools:context="com.example.razze.roomee.MainActivity"
 tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

as said above try removing your Action Bar also try removing  padding top in your content main

`android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"`

Comment: I have tried ajusting it to "0dp", and that had no effect. Tried removing it, had no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer.

I had a similar problem, but in my case it was just that Android Studio had automatically added `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in the xml of one of my activities. Even if the bar is hidden the size attribute seems to persist.

Just in case someone runs into something similar.